# openpyxl - не записывает в ячейки

Tags: python, excel

Не записывает в ячейки, помогите плезз

```
import os, sys
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='qwe.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Лист1']

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='asd.xlsx')

sheet2 = wb['Лист1']

for i in range(1, 5):
val = sheet['A'+str(i)].value
print(val)

sheet2['A'+str(i)].value = val
wb2.save('asd.xlsx')


wb.save('qwe.xlsx')
wb2.save('asd.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас опечатка:

```
sheet2 = wb['Лист1']
# -------^^
```

вы открыли `sheet2` лист в том же файле, что и `sheet` и, соответственно, читаете и пишете данные в одном и том же файле - `qwe.xlsx`.

Чтобы исправить:

```
sheet2 = wb2['Лист1']
```